# xyplot, Error in `[.xts`(y, id) : 'i' or 'j' out of range

Tags: r, xts, lattice

I am trying to scatter plot two variables, one of which is the residuals from an `lm()` call. The `xyplot()` function will not do this scatter plot and returns the error message

```
Error in `[.xts`(y, id) : 'i' or 'j' out of range
```

The residuals are an xts variable and `xyplot()` can in fact still plot the residuals by itself (just a time plot, not a scatter plot).

Strangely, the work around I've found so far is to use `as.xts()` on the already xts residuals, or to use `[ ,1]` indexing to refer to the first column, even though there is only one column to begin with.

MWE is below, just looking for an explanation, thanks in advance.

```
library('lattice')
library('xts')
a = as.xts(ts(rnorm(20), start=c(1980,1), freq=4))
b = as.xts(ts(rnorm(20), start=c(1980,1), freq=4))

c = resid(lm(a~b))
str(c) # xts object

xyplot(c~a) # does not work: Error in `[.xts`(y, id) : 'i' or 'j' out of range
xyplot(c) # xyplot can plot it by itself just fine
xyplot(as.xts(c)~a) # works, if you use as.xts() on an xts object ?
xyplot(c[ ,1]~a) # works, if you refer to the 1st column of a 1 column object ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because `c` doesn't have a `dim` attribute, like most xts objects do, and how many xts functions expect xts objects to have.  Set the `dim` attribute and everything's okay.

```
dim(c) <- c(length(c),1)
xyplot(c~a)
```